# E: Unable to locate package protonvpn on Ubuntu

Tags: apt, 20.04

I wanna Install Protonvpn on my ubuntu 20+ but couldn't, I don't know what's going on!

Even Updating with apt-get update doesn't make any sense

I use this command:

```
sudo apt-get install protonvpn
```

Response:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package protonvpn
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Proton VPN is not distributed by Ubuntu.

You must obtain it from the the company directly.

If you want to know why, ask Proton VPN. It's their decision.